# Ensuring with-statement calls __exit__() when KeyboardInterrupt during await

Tags: python, python-asyncio, with-statement

Consider the following code:

```py
import asyncio


class Resource:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("-- enter --")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("-- exit --")


async def main():
    with Resource():
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I expect `__exit__()` is called even when I press Ctrl+C during awaiting `sleep(10)`, but it isn't. How to ensure the cleanup?

Comment: Using `asyncio.run(main())` instead of the `loop` syntax goes through `__exit__`. Are you attached to the loop?

Comment: Could also have a look at [async with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-async-with-statement) statement.

Comment: This is a long-standing problem: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0419/ https://bugs.python.org/issue29988. The issue occurs even without async. Ctrl+C can raise an exception basically anywhere in your code, and even try/finally or context managers are not guaranteed to run properly. The closest thing to a solution that I've found is using the `signal` library to write your own handler for SIGINT, though this does not work on Windows.

Comment: I just got to know `asyncio.run()` but actually I have to work with Python 3.6 so `asyncio.run()` is not present.

Comment: I don't want to make this script unix-only, but If I use signal library to solve this issue, do I need to store all resources in somewhere globally accessible (such as global variables)?